# How to bookmark a Primeng date checkbox?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Hi community, I am using primeng and I show in a table records that come from a database, I want to check my checkbox according to the response of the database, if the language is active I should load the check in true but I do not know how to access for mark it

```
<p-dataTable [value]="userLanguage" name="userLang" dataKey="key">
 <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
 <p-column field="languageName" header="Idioma"></p-column>
 <p-column field="languageId" header="Código"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Component:

```
 // Obtener los idiomas del usuario
   getLanguage(user){
    this._userService.getLanguage(user).subscribe(
      response => {
      this.userLanguage = response.lstLOV;
    }, 
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

on your datatable definition, add a `[(selection)]="selectedLanguages"` property.
on your component definition, add a variable called `selectedLanguages: Language[] = [];`
In your `getLanguage` function, use a `forEach` on your `this.userLanguage` and check to see if it is marked active, if it is, push the language to the `this.selectedLanguage` variable.  Be sure to set the `this.selectedLanguages = []` as one of the first things on your `getLanguage` call

For an example of using selections, see the selections subsection of the datatable component  [Showcase showing selections](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/selection)